# Flash doesn't work in firefox after upgrade Kubuntu to 14.10

Tags: upgrade, firefox, kubuntu, flash

I upgraded Kubuntu 14.04-x64 to 14.10. Now flash does not work in Firefox. Now flash is an empty area which sometimes is black when cursor is under it.

But flash still works in Chromium.

Comment: Are you using Beta(14.10) or GA, which has been released today?

Comment: Released today.

Comment: Flash plugin 15.0.0.189 /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so

Comment: Pepper flash won't work on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try install flash player again and pepper teacup by typing in the terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Unable to locate package flash-plugins

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get install flash-plugin pepper teacup.

Comment: Not yet. I would like to use official Adobe Flash.

Comment: This ppa installs a windows version of OFFICIAL flash as a plugin supported by FF.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe flash player version is not updated for Ubuntu from version 11.2. So many websites notify to update flash player and some websites with not working issues. Try the flash player in this link http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-fresh-player-plugin-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```